# How to parse some byte arrays in function with "params"?

Tags: c#, arrays, arrayofarrays

I have written this function:

```
    public static Mp3FileReader GetSoundsFromFiles(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return new Mp3FileReader(new MemoryStream(bytes));
    }
```

And I need to parse some byte arrays with keyword "params" instead of one. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. You want your `GetSoundsFromFiles` method to get multiple `byte[]`s and concatenate them into one big `byte[]` and create a memory stream of it?

Comment: @Emad, I need to create an array of byte[] arrays and create MemoryStream from each array

Comment: if you are going to read MP3, this might be helpful: byte[] byteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using a list of byte arrays would do the trick for you, like this:

```
public static List<Mp3FileReader> GetSoundsFromFiles(List<byte[]> bytes)
{
    List<Mp3FileReader> soundList=new List<Mp3FileReader>();
    foreach (var a in bytes)
    {
        soundList.Add(new Mp3FileReader(new MemoryStream (a));
    }
    return soundList;
}
```

Comment: i need to wait 4 mintues